# Discrete implementation of High-Speed High-Low Side MOSFET Driver?

Tags: power-electronics

The IR2101 is a popular driver choice for MOSFET half H-Bridges. Its functional diagram is as follows:

[image: 2101 Diagram]

I would like to implement a high-speed high and low side driver using only DISCRETE components, with BJTs for the push-pull circuitry. I do not need undervoltage detection or a high voltage level shift, as I am using a high-side logic level P-Channel FET. Abstractly, what would this circuit look like?

High-Side: AOD403
Low-Side: IRLR8726

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: "Abstractly, what would this circuit look like?" It would look like two low-side drivers...The whole point of the schematic posted is the bootstrapping and level shift but you said you don't need any of that.

Comment: @The Photon Sorry, I meant to ask how to implement the discrete circuit (ie. What can I throw out of the functional diagram for this professional driver to make my life simpler without it failing to work)

Comment: Just note that the PMOS limiting factor is NOT the max  Vds. It is the max Vgs.

Comment: @DKNguyen I am aware. I will need to use a zener diode, preferably with a Rbv of 10-12v...

Comment: Is your question what would a gate driver look like if it was driving the gate relative to VDC instead of ground (gate is either VDC for OFF or VDC - 15V for ON)? But had a control input referenced to ground? In essence, what does an upside down low side gate driver look like? That eliminates the Vgs limiting factor